# req.body is an empty object express/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a form with two numeric input fields that I'd like to send to the backend, but req.body is always empty. Here is my form:

```
<form
    class="mt-3"
    id="myForm"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    action="/submit-thing1and2"
  >
    <div class="mb-2">
      <label for="thing1" class="form-label"
        >Thing 1</label
      >
      <input
        type="number"
        class="form-control"
        id="thing1"
        name="thing1"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
      <label for="thing2" class="form-label"
        >Thing 2</label
      >
      <input
        type="number"
        class="form-control"
        id="thing2"
        name="thing2"
        required
      />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group-row mb-3">
      <button id="submitThings" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Submit Things
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I have tried using enctype="application/json", "text/html", and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", and all of them still return an empty object in req.body.

Here is my post request:

```
form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", async (event, arg) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(event.target.action);
  console.log(event.target);
  let data = new FormData(event.target);
  console.log(data.toString());

  fetch(event.target.action, {
    method: "post",
    body: new FormData(event.target),
  })
   .then((res) => {
     console.log(res.status);
     return res.text();
  })
   .then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And here is my server-side handling of the post request - the console.log works, just shows an empty object:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.post("/submit-thing1and2", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req.body", req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./html/index.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: The content type of your POST request is `multipart/formdata` but `express.urlencoded` only covers `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So it does not know how to parse it. Also you are using the FormData class which packs the data into the `multipart/formdata` format no matter what. So when trying `application/json` or `urlencoded` as contenttype you get a missmatch on type and actual body content.

Comment: @Palladium02 when I change it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded it still returns an empty object :(

Comment: Yes as I explained in the second part of my comment, you are using the FormData class in your frontend code which will pack your data into the `multipart/formdata` format. So you need to parse it as such on your backend, also you need to set the contenttype header accordingly so the parser middlewares can detect it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to parse `multipart/form-data` requests:

```js
app.post("/submit-thing1and2",
  multer().fields([{name: "thing1"}, {name: "thing2"}]),
  async function(req, res) {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: I was missing something similar to this - I am already using multer and adding upload.none() solved my problem.